# OAuth authentication and consumer secrets

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a webservice which acts as backend for smartphone apps.

I want to be able to authenticate users as painless as possible, but even though I thought I understood the OAuth I must admit there are some missing pieces here and there.

**Authentication:**

Let's say the user has an Android phone. He is probably already Authenticated to Google and it would be really nice if I could just extend this authentication to my webservice. Android has OAuth support so the users opens his app, grants permissions to use his google account and the app authenticates him to the web service.

**Web service**

Since the service should accept users from all kinds of devices it should not be Google specific. It should be possible to register an account and login from any device. I'm unsure if it is possible to register a new account with OAuth alone or if you need some other kind of authentication first - OpenID for instance.

How would the flow be for the generic webservice? A generic API for registering a user and granting him access to an API?

Furthermore - I do not want to control the devices connecting to this service. I can see OAuth requires a consumer_key and a consumer_secret. If I run everything through SSL - is the consumer secret still secret or can I just use some dummy values? Thus avoiding creating a device-registration system where people can acquire a consumer_secret?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, if you want to use Google/Facebook etc as authentication providers, you will need to use the 'Authorization Code' flow of Oauth2. In this case, you register with Google/FB as a developer and get a client id and secret for using their API.

Then you obtain the Login with Google/Facebook button and code, which you will use to fire a "webview" or an embedded browser where the user will be taken to google/facebook and asked to provide his login credentials.

Upon success, an authorization code will be sent to a redirect url that you would have provided while registering as a developer at Google/Facebook. You will need to catch this authorization code and then again call the relevant API to obtain the access token, which you can then use to fetch the user's details to register him in case of first time or authenticate him if he's already registered through this method earlier.